# Ant: Run java project from basedir, with compiled classes in build

Tags: ant

I have a project which is built using Ant.  I have a task which compiles the source and classes the .class files into a build. directory.  I also have a task which packages up the .class files into a jar file located at bin/project.jar

I have two tasks to run the project.  One runs the project using the jar file, the other from the class files.  They are configured in the following manner:

```
<target name="run" depends="compile" description="run the project">
  <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="${main.class}" fork="yes">
      <arg line="${args}"/>
  </java>
</target>

<target name="runjar" depends="jar" description="run the project from jar file">
  <java jar="${jar.dir}/Project.jar" fork="true">
      <arg line="${args}"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

If I run the task `run`, the current working directory is `/home/me/project/build/`

If I run the task `runjar`, the current working directory is `/home/me/project/`

I don't want the extra `build/` in my current working directory.  How can I change the `run` task to set the current working directory properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `dir` to the project directory.  Then add classpath, with a location pointing to the `build.dir`.

```
<target name="run" depends="compile" description="run the project">
  <java dir="${project.dir}" classname="${main.class}" fork="yes">
      <arg line="${args}"/>
       <classpath>
           <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
       </classpath>
  </java>
</target>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great!  I set my project.dir to '.'